# How to update Django in visual studio 2017

Tags: django, python-3.x, visual-studio

I am trying to setup Visual Studio 2017 for Django Development but the Django (1.9) version is old, How can I update it to latest version (>= 2.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can go through this link https://djangobook.com/developing-django-visual-studio/  this is a complete setup guide.i hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Create a Django Web Project with proposed install. Name Your Env.

1. choose "Python Environment"
2. choose your Enviroment
3. choose Packages (PyPi)
4. choose available Updates

[image]